# If Relativity says there is no way to discern the 'real' frame between 2 inertial frames of reference, then how does energy play into this?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, energy-conservation

It's been about a year since I touched (special) relativity so this question may be a bit nonsensical.

We know that special relativity tells us that each inertial frame of reference is equal and valid. As in if a ball and myself are in a black empty vacuum moving relative to each other, both of us are equally 'moving'. But I also know that kinetic energy equals $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. Meaning shouldn't the ball and I have different energies relative to each other? And if not, wouldn't this mean I can discern who is 'really' moving? Can someone explain what concepts I'm missing to understand the relation between energy and relativity?

Comment: So you and I disagree about how much kinetic energy the ball has.  How exactly do you propose to exploit this disagreement to determine which of us is "really" moving?

Comment: I was under the impression that if you could show one has 0 energy, while the other has a certain non-zero energy, you could utilize that fact to show that one is 'really' moving. As the object with non-zero energy is the only one capable of moving because it has non-zero energy, while the ball has no energy thus violates the requirement that if it was moving it would have $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ energy. But as the answer below indicates (and others I've found on google using the terminology of the answer below) I've realized that energy indeed varies on the contrary to my intuition.

Answer (score 6):

Energy is frame variant. It transforms as the timelike component of the four momentum $(E/c,p_x,p_y,p_z)$.

Energy is also conserved. No frame is privileged, each will have a different value for energy but each will agree on energy conservation and on any experimental outcome related to the energy.

Comment: Would this mean it is non-sensical to ask the question "what is the total amount of energy in Joules of the universe" ? Before finding out that energy is frame variant I was under the impression that that question had a real number answer.

Comment: @onetwo well, that question is problematic for a different reason. The problem with that question is that when spacetime is curved there isn’t even a clear way to add the four-momentum in different locations to get a total four-momentum. So even if you accept some frame by convention, you still cannot get a total. The total energy is thus not merely frame variant but rather it is undefined

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not unique to special relativity. The same property applies in newtonian mechanics, since newtonian mechanics also features the principle of relativity of inertial motion.

(Specifically: newtonian mechanics and SR mechanics have in common that the *Principle of relativity of inertial motion* is recognized. The difference is that in terms of newtonian mechanics it is assumed that galilean transformation is applicable, and in terms of SR it is assumed that Lorentz transformation is applicable.)

For simplicity I will limit to collision between two objects.

In any collision event the amount of kinetic energy involved in that collision event is exclusively determined by the *relative velocity* between the two objects involved in the collision.

One way to examine that is as follows:
Take two objects, $m_1$ and $m_2$, with different mass, and describe the velocity of each as the velocity with respect to the common center of mass (CCOM) of the two.

So: that first evaluation is using a coordinate system that is co-moving with the common center of mass of the two objects. That gives you the kinetic energy involved in a collision event.

Next: express the total velocity attributed to each object in the following way: as the sum of:

- the velocity of each object wrt the CCOM
- the velocity of the CCOM wrt the coordinate system you are using.

(Of course, for the coordinate system you must use one of the members of the equivalence class of inertial coordinate systems.)

If you work that out you find that the evaluation shows that the kinetic energy involved in the collision is independent of the choice of coordinate system (among the equivalence class of inertial coordinate systems).

What that means is that kinetic energy is not something that is intrinsic to a single object. Instead kinetic energy is intrinsically related to the *relative velocity* between *two* objects.